# How to suppress footer on individual page?

Tags: header-footer

I've got a report document that consists of daily and weekly reports. Each week gets its corresponding shorthanded five days report on one page and a more detailed full week report on the second page. So it's two pages for each week. Each list of five days and each full week report gets a signature line in its footer. So if there are only one paged week reports there will be a signature line on every page but the title page (title page without headers and footers actually works like a charm).

Each week is started by a \newpage command and there is a \newpage between the daily and the full week report. So it looks somehow like this:

```
[titlepage]
[ 
  - day 1 | lorem ipsum
  - day 2 | lorem ipsum
  - day 3 | lorem ipsum
  - day 4 | lorem ipsum
  - day 5 | lorem ipsum


  _______________
  signature             #pageno
  \newpage
]
[
  full week lorem ipsum


  _______________
  signature             #pageno
  \newpage
]
```

Now, on a week report that does not fit on a single page I'd like to have the signature line only on the last page of the detailed week report. That is, I'd like to suppress the signature line on every page that does not end with \newpage, i.e. that is automatically wrapped because of its content being to long.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `\pagestyle{empty}` or `\pagestyle{plain}`  generally so the footer isn't used on the automatic pages then on the forced pages you can use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` or whatever page style you are using to get the page style required. As always it would be much easier to answer (and test the code) if you supplied a full small working example in the question.

Comment: Would be okay, but... I'd need to use \thispagestyle on every page I'd like the footer to appear... isn't there sort of the opposite way like having it on every page by default and just hiding it on single pages I don't want it on? Or even automatically hiding the footer on pages that are not wrapped manually by using \newpage? Know what I mean?

**edit** I've made it by adding \thispagestyle{empty} above the content parameter (it's a \newcommand actually) and \thispagestyle{scrheadings} after the content. Header and footer are only added on the last page of a detailed week report now.

Comment: ... but I'd like to remove just the signature line and leave the other footers and headers unimpaired. **//edit** ... what works by defining a custom style with empty definition for outer left footer. Alright! I've managed it!

Comment: If you are using forced breaks anyway with \newpage there is no real extra needed to use instead \mynewpage which is defined to be \newpage\thispagestyle{abc} where abc style is defined to be just like the other style but with a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically partially hidden footers can be achieved by creating a custom style (adding a .sty file in the same directory the .tex file is lying). In my special case it looks kinda like this...

**Method 1**

Firstly the footers (example.tex):

```
\lofoot{Left odd footer}
\lefoot{Left even footer}
```

Secondly the command (example.tex):

```
\newcommand{\example}[2]{
    \section*{#1}
    \thispagestyle{custom}
    #2
    \thispagestyle{scrheadings}
    \newpage
}
```

Thirdly the style (custom.sty)

```
\newcommand{\ps@custom}
    \lofoot{} % empty left footers
    \lefoot{} % empty left footers
}
```

... which means that the style stays scrheadings on one page week reports and gets changed to custom on reports with more than one page.

This is a somewhat dirty solution at least for reports (using \example command which looks and is named a little bit different here) that consist of one or two pages. I haven't tested it against reports consisting of three or more pages, yet. Maybe someone could predict in a comment how this might behave there...

**Method 2 - redefining \newpage (or defining an appropriate substitute)**

Just to mention: this is somehow the inversion of *Method 1*. It's **not** defining a **general** footer for signature that appears on any page but those that are automatically wrapped (like *Method 1*). It **only** defines footers for pages that **are manually** wrapped.

So, with a redefinition of the \newpage command one can achieve this goal too. If you only want a footer to appear on a page previous to one that has been started by a manual page break, just do the following somewhere before your \begin{document} or in a custom page style. Like this for instance:

```
\renewcommand{\newpage}{
    \lofoot{
        \begin{tabular}{p{10cm}}
        \hline Unterschrift \\
        \end{tabular}
    }

    \lefoot{
        \begin{tabular}{p{10cm}}
        \hline Unterschrift \\
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \pagebreak
    \lefoot{}
    \lefoot{}
}
```